# How do I extract the graphics from a Google Presentation template for use with Beamer (LaTeX)?

Tags: google-slides

I have a Google Presentation template (the title page and a slide) and I want to extract the graphics from it (so that I can use it later with [LaTeX/Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244412/46529)).

How do I do that?

PS. Note that this is not about [an individual image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244412/46529) but about a style template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one could do that, I think Google Apps Script would be my best bet. Currently it is  not possible in Google Apps Script to access a Google Slide that way. See this enhancement request in the Google Apps Script issue tracker, to make that possible:

- **[issue 1573](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1573)**

As mentioned in the issue itself:

> To subsequent readers: If you are also interested in this requested
>   feature, please click the star next to the issue number.